# Mega-menu tab on multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, xml

I would like to create a tab in SharePoint 2007 that is a mega menu.  This mega menu tab will be implemented on multiple site collections.   It will be a part of the global navigation in each site collection

Has anyone done this before?  May I please get some guidance/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [Archetonomy](http://www.archetonomy.com/), they have a product that I have used before - I'm not affiliated with this company.

Comment: It looks like its for 2013 and not 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://www.teylyn.com/articles/sharepoint-articles/sharepoint-mega-menu-from-a-dvwp-and-a-list/) describes how to create a dynamic mega menu with a DVWP and a list. It has been written for SP 2010 but can be applied in the same way for 2007.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, it looks like you are the author of the article.  Question, when creating the "MegaMenu Content" list, is it safe to skip the following column (MegaHeader:Order).  When I try and create that column, "Order" does not appear in the drop down when when look up is selected and "MegaMenu Header" is the list.  What can I do in its place?

Comment: I made the "Order" column a string in the MegaHeader list and it appeared in  the drop down.  I'll see how that goes.

Comment: The MegaMenu Content list has a lookup field into the MegaHeader list. The MegaHeader:Order gets created automatically when you tick the box during the definition of the lookup column.

Comment: Ok. Thanks!  I got the to the point where my DVWP appears as a nested UL-LI-UL-LI construct.  But when I add the style sheet, everything disappears.  Any ideas?  THanks!

Comment: If you've gotten that far, the rest is just CSS, not SharePoint. You need to gain an understanding of how CSS works and is applied. The top level UL>LI has images as a background fill. The nested UL>LI have surrounding divs that are positioned with CSS. If you're new to CSS, try it one element at a time. Use Developer Tools (F12 in IE) to identify styles applied to screen elements.

Comment: Ok..I'm stuck.  I still get the bullets and no headings (https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3vy2q9uyw9elx1/ONR_NAV.PNG) but when I hover over, the sub-menus appear (https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wo0s26cp7u3x6y/ONR_NAV2.PNG).  Also, it only creates one column but not 3.  What am I doing wrong?  I've played with the lists, looked at the xsl but can't figure out what's wrong.  Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It's impossible to tell what is wrong with your CSS without seeing your CSS. The styling for the mega menu is not trivial. My article has a [link to a sample page](http://www.teylyn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/mega-dropdown.html) that is pure html, not SharePoint. Study the html and the CSS for this page. Then look at the html that is rendered by the SharePoint DVWP. My final CSS has some customisations which are explained in my article.