# Targeting SharePoint 2013 Built-in Navbar

Tags: sharepoint-online, global-navigation, sharepoint-addin, navbars

SharePoint's built-in navigation appears to create a `<ul>` inside of a `<div>`, but the id on this inner `<ul>` appears to change between pages.

In the two below screenshots are examples of the same built-in navigation, but on different pages (notice the id's are `zz10_RootAspMenu` vs `zz11_RootAspMenu`).

[image: Example with zz10...]

[image: Example with zz11...]

I am attempting to make an add-in that can target and replace this `<ul>` with my own custom menu.

Any idea how this `zz___` id is determined and whether there are other variations that can be seen? Is this a good id to use as a hook for my Javascript or is there something else that may work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of targeting the exact ID, you can look for IDs **ending with** `_TopNavigationMenu` or `_RootAspMenu`.

If you're using CSS you can access the `<ul>` via [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp):

```
/* ul whose id is ending with "_RootAspMenu" within a div
   whose id is ending with "_TopNavigationMenu" */
div[id$=_TopNavigationMenu] ul[id$=_RootAspMenu] { color: pink; }
```

In case you use JavaScript / jQuery there is also such an ["ends with selector"](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$("div[id$='_TopNavigationMenu'] ul[id$='_RootAspMenu']").css("color", "pink");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest to hook this `ID=zz10_RootAspMenu` in your JavaScript. SharePoint has its own internal way to generate `IDs`.

I had an experience where I was trying to hook the `DIV` above this `UL` which you are trying access. But on different environment which had an update, was generating different ID.

**So do not use SharePoint generated ID which has tendency to change as a hook, to get things done.**

Instead the best practice would be to, open up your master page and place another `DIV` with your own `UniqueID` around the `UL` or it's `parent DIV`. Then use this DIV with UniqueID as a hook in your JavaScript. See the reference JS below

```
var i = 0;
var ul = null;
jQuery("div#YourDivId ul").each(function () {
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        ul = this.id.toString();
        return false;
    }
});
ul = jQuery("ul#" + ul);
```

Similarly you can go through [Mega Menu On Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130597/mega-menu-on-sharepoint-2013/139685#139685)

Comment: Or just use a suffix matching selector in CSS or jQuery to avoid modifiying a whole maste page just for this

Comment: @RobertLindgren: Yep thats a better approach if you want only this to be achieved rather than unnecessary updating `Master Page` and an overload of `JavaScript`. But if you already have a custom master page and many changes have been done and already maintaining a `JavaScript`, then this approach can be useful.