# how to do drop down menu in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: dropdown

[image]I wanted do drop down global navigation menu in two and three column. How I will achieve this using SharePoint 2013? Kindly help me. Snapshot is attached with this what I actually want.
In advance Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any snap shot of what you like to build up?

Comment: I have attached snapshot to this. kindly help.

Comment: Read http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130597/mega-menu-on-sharepoint-2013/139685#139685

Comment: Thanks Asad. Now I am using metadata navigation for my site. But I have one problem now. My term sets are showing in different levels(level1,level2,level3), but I need only two levels and second level term set should be in column as in snapshot. Is I am missing something?

Comment: Actually I want this solution:                   http://support.bind.pt/hc/en-us/articles/204448019-Setup-Mega-Menu-SharePoint-2013-and-Office-365-2013-                                                   But I didn't get "$('#MenuH .MenuBar ul.root').BindMENU({ MenuStyle:"DefaultMenu",Orientation:"Horizontal" });" ths line in my master page.

Comment: You can use developer tool and see in which element id, does your menu exist.

Comment: I used developer tool but its showing SharePoint default div classes only i.e. (static dynamic-children selected, menu-item-text,dynamic dynamic-children, dynamic menu-item ms-core-list Menu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode)

Comment: I have created one js file as=$(document).ready(function()
{
alert('managed');
var i = 0;
var ul = null;
$("#menu_barL1 ul").each(function () {
alert('inside');
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        ul = this.id.toString();
        alert(ul);
        return false;
    }
});
ul = $("ul" + ul);
});

Comment: and css file as=//Remove first level classes
ul.children(".dynamic-children").removeClass("dynamic-children").addClass("menu_barL1");

// Replace OOB class and set with your custom for level 2
var liCustomDynamicChildren = ul.children("li.menu_barL1");
liCustomDynamicChildren.children("ul").removeClass("dynamic").addClass("menu_barL2");

// Replace OOB class and set with your custom for Level 3
jQuery("ul.menu_barL2").children("li.dynamic-children").children("ul.dynamic").removeClass("dynamic").addClass("menu_barL3");

Comment: Copied ur code #Asad

Comment: You need to get hold of SharePoint default classes and get rid of them..

Answer (score 2):

Try this links ,
This is brief intro to how the Top Navigation (also known as Global Navigation) functions Out of the Box. Note: I am not talking about an easy solution to creating a consistent Navigation between Site Collections

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/11/22/how-to-configure-a-drop-down-menu-on-the-top-link-bar-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

https://sharepointotoole.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/global-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013/

https://newsignature.com/articles/no-code-global-navigation-flyout-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-online

Comment: This is not what I want. Actually I did structural navigation and its same as vertical links. I want 1st level only vertical as well horizontal links (column level drop down menu). In advance thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you can achive this using Manage MetaData and Navigation OOTB
kindly Refer below Link this will help you get your result
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15876.sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata.aspx

Thanks

Comment: I tried with managed metadata but term set is not getting created. It shows this error: "Failed to create term set: A default managed metadata service connection hasn't been specified". For this I started managed metadata service application, but same output.

Comment: You need to associate your metadata application with the default application proxy group. Go to Central Admin > Application Management > Configure Service application associations.

In the top right corner on the page, change the view to Service Applications. Click the "default" proxy group and check the box for your second Metadata application. Click OK and try again. and at the end reset IIS and Sharepoint Timer Service hope this will resolve issue

Comment: This also I tried but same output.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23388.sharepoint-2013-failed-to-create-term-set-a-default-managed-metadata-service-connection-hasnt-been-specified.aspx